# FontForge - Add stroke to font with fill color and generate font

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype, fontforge

I need to apply a black outline to a font but maintain the white fill color. Expanding the stroke or adding an outline style applies the outline, but when I generate the .ttf or the .otf, the fill color is lost. I've never used fontforge before and a lot of the terms in the documentation are lost on me. Any guidance is appreciated. Using Windows 10.

Comment: Note that as is, this is not a programming question, it's a question about using the "FontForge" type design application, for which there are far better places to ask. You probably want https://typedrawers.com if you want the help of professional typographers, otherwise: FontForge is open source software with a public issue tracker, if you want to do something that you can't find any guidance for in their documentation, that's something they'll probably want to know about so that the documentation can be improved/ammended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a OpenType font, glyphs are described as shape outlines that get filled by a TrueType or CFF (PostScript type 1) rasterizer. The rasterizer is determining which regions are *interior* to the outline and, accordingly, which pixels get "ink". But the rasterizer doesn't determine the colour. It's up to the application to determine what colour is used for the glyph shape interior (the "foreground" colour) and what colour is used for the background.

Many graphics apps allow you to set a fill colour separate from the stroke colour. But the way that is done is to draw the text using the fill colour as foreground colour (as text would normally be drawn), and then separately to obtain the outline data from the font and then to draw that as paths on top of the "fill". In effect, the app is using the outlines twice in two different modes.

You can create a font that appears as outline stroke with a fill where the foreground colour applies to the outline and the background colour applies to the fill. E.g.,

[image: sample of the Resta font]

These kinds of fonts are often referred to as "outline" fonts. (Don't get confused with the technical sense of "outline" to mean the paths in a font's glyph data.) Here's another example of the same font but with the foreground colour set to red and the background set to light green:

[image: sample of the Resta with different foreground and background colours]

The way that would be done is that the glyph outline includes the outer and inner contours of the stroke.

[image: Glyph outlines for capital T in the Rest font]

The rasterizer will turn on pixels only for the interior regions of the combined paths.

So far, this is describing typical monochrome fonts. If you want to control the colour of the outline stroke and the fill within the font, then you can create a *colour* font. Unlike typical monochrome fonts, in which the font doesn't specify any colour info and the app determines foreground and background colours, colour fonts have polychromatic glyphs in which the font developer specifies particular colours. See [here](https://www.colorfonts.wtf/) for an overview of colour fonts (a little dated and doesn't mention recent enhancements, but still a good intro).

The OpenType spec supports different formats for colour fonts:

- using embedded colour bitmaps
- using embedded SVG
- using standard glyph outlines as shapes but with the ability to combine them in layers with specified colours or to apply other graphic operations

I don't know if Fontforge supports creation of colour fonts, but other font development apps such as [FontCreator](https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator), [FontLab](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab/) and [Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/) do have support for colour fonts.

Comment: Do you know any freeware tool supported creation of colour fonts ?

Comment: @SeRgI: check out nanoemoji: https://github.com/googlefonts/nanoemoji